# Can I run asp.net mvc 1 on .net 4?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, .net-4.0

I have a asp.net mvc site that references a couple of libraries. Recently I discovered that it is necessary to migrate those dlls to .net 4 (I mean compile them for .net 4). Can I run asp.net mvc 1 on .net 4. Migration to asp.net mvc 2 is postponed because of the removal of **response.WriteSubstitution(...)** method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything that works on C# 3.5 should work on C# 4.

To be certain, try using [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#BuildComparison) to verify dependancies.